# How to ensure if drl file is loaded by KIE

Tags: drools

Is there any quick way to check programmatically if DRL file is loaded successfully by the drools library within our web application? BTW, I am developing soap based web service using drools. For ex: listing out all the rule names present in the knowledge base at a certain time etc.
Please help.
This is what I am doing to load the drl file from centOS filesystem:

```
String drlFile = "/tmp/conf/object.drl";
ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( drlFile );
kfs.write("/Drools/Object.drl",ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ));
KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
```

Comment: Try this `Collection<KiePackage> packages = kbase.getKiePackages();
for( KiePackage pack: packages )
{
    for(Rule ru : pack.getRules())
    {
        // Save somewhere or print
        //System.out.println(ru.getId()+" "+ru.getName()+"-"+ru.getPackageName()+"-"+ru.getMetaData());
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried this, but the collection packages is empty. Its showing size as zero. This is what I am doing to load the drl file from filesystem: String drlFile = "/tmp/conf/object.drl"

ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( drlFile );

kfs.write("/Drools/Object.drl",ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ));

KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();

Comment: The issue is not resolved. I need help from the expert.

Comment: Add the kmodule.xml code

Comment: I am not using kmodule.xml in my application at all. Should I be using it?

Comment: yes, try using it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to detect errors on a build all is to pull up the messages on the results from the buildAll().

```
kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)
or
kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages()
```

as a side note*

I had a similar issue where buildAll() was not reading the file I wrote inside  the kfs. The symptoms were the same where no packages were in the collection.

To fix that issue I had to add a specific resource type to the inputStream.
e.g.

```
kfs.write("/Drools/Object.drl",ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));
```

For determining the packages inside the ksession I always have used.

```
ksession.getKieBase().getKiePackages()
```

For detecting the files my builder knew about and loaded I used this

```
((MemoryKieModule)kb.getKieModule()).getFileNames()
```